# TypeScript - error TS5023: Unknown compiler option '-r'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm working on Windows environment and trying to run a forked node.js + typescript project.

This is my `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "my-task",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc-watch --onSuccess 'node -r source-map-support/register .'",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint --cache '{src,test}/**/*.ts'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.53",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "get-port": "^5.1.1",
    "got": "^11.5.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.8.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.20.0",
    "jest": "^26.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.4",
    "tsc-watch": "^4.2.9",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

For some reason, i'm getting the following error:

```
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option '-r'.
```

I tried to remove the -r, but then i'm getting these errors:

```
error TS6054: File '.'' has an unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
error TS6231: Could not resolve the path 'source-map-support/register' with the extensions: '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
```

and server won't start.
I ran `npm uninstall` + `npm install` - nothing seems to solve these issues.
Can anyone assist?

**EDITED:**

ts.config:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your ```tsconfg.json``` file. Can you post your file here?

Comment: Try to run _npm run tsc_ in the root of the project. If you got no error then add "tsc": "tsc" right below your _"lint": ..._ line. Otherwise it would be useful to see what error you get.

Comment: I added the ts.config file

Comment: @JoseVasquez there is no "tsc" defined under scripts. it does not work

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes?

`tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node -r source-map-support/register .\"`

Comment: Did you solve this issue?